how to create entity for specific product
I'm making an e-commerce website and i have product entity with basic properties
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public string? ImageUrl { get; set; }
    public int? CategoryId { get; set; }
    public Category? Category { get; set; }
    public string? Brand { get; set; }
}

So if I'm not wrong if i want to create a laptop i need to make another entity and inherit from Product,is this right approach? because i will have to make table for every specific product

Creating table for each product is bad approach,
instead you can do some normalization and create table for ProductType and Product Properties
using System;
public class Product
{
      public int Id { get; set; }
      [Required]
      public string Name { get; set; }
      [Required]
      public decimal Price { get; set; }
      public string? ImageUrl { get; set; }
      public int? CategoryId { get; set; }
      public Category? Category { get; set; }
      public string? Brand { get; set; }

      public int ProductTypeID{get;set;}//foreign key
}

//psuedo code
public class ProductTypes//here in this table u can store all product types laptop etc
{
    public int ID{get;set;}
    public string TypeName{get;set;}//laptop, tv, webcam
}

public class ProductProperties
{
    public int ID{get;set;}
    public int ProductID{get;set;}//foreign key
    public string PropertyName{get;set;}//ram, storage
    public string PropertyValue{get;set;}//1gb,500gb
}


You should not create a table for every specific product, this defeats the purpose of having a "product" table in the first place.
Instead, your products e.g. "Laptop" should become rows in your "product" table.
E.g.:
Product laptop = new Product();
laptop.Name = "Laptop"
laptop.Price = 499; // Etc. for other properties
// some logic to save your laptop product


but what if i want to add more details like ram, storage properties how is that gonna work
